# Pass a block to Sass mixin results in "mixin doesn't accept a content block"

Tags: sass, block, mixins

I can't get a mixin to accept a block:

```
=my-mixin($some-var)
  width: $some-var
  @content // Is this correct?

+my-mixin(123px)
  height: 100px
```

This results in a "mixin doesn't accept a content block" error. I'm using the current version of Sass. Thanks for help.

Comment: Hmm - not sure what the problem is here. i used your code for this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kfpmz.  the only thing i can think of is that you need to sass/compass

Answer (score 3):

syntax is ok with version 3.2 of SASS, double check that

Comment: Can you document the error and solution in your question so others can find it?

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was with SASS indentation.

You can't nest another block within a mixin like this:

```
.button-cta
  +button (transparent, tomato)
    &:hover
      background-color: tomato
      color: #fff
```

instead:

```
  .button-cta
    +button (transparent, tomato)
    &:hover
      background-color: tomato
      color: #fff
```

hover state must not be nested

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too. Turned out that somewhere else in my scss I was using `@mixin mobile-only` instead of `@include mobile-only` - aka, I was accidentally redefining the mixin later in the code.